# When using the quality parameter in sharp.js to compress a PNG, many of the images are the same file size

Tags: javascript, node.js, image-compression, sharpjs

I'm trying to compress PNGs using sharp.js and I'm trying to find the correct values that I would like to use in the final program. I made a basic for loop that changes the `quality` parameter by 5, starting from 0 to 100. This works well until it reaches 15%, there is still some compression after that but the file size and photo overall looks the same (well I dont see any differences). Here is the function that I've called:

```
await sharp(img.data)
    .png({
    quality: i,
    force: true,
})
.toFile(`./output/${i}.png`);
```

i is just the number and img.data is coming from an express server using the image in the post request (req.files.image).

Here is also what I see in file explorer (the file name corresponds to what `i` was when making the file):[image: File explorer showing the size of the image and the quality applied to it by the file name]

Answer (score 0):

> `options.palette` boolean  quantise to a palette-based image with alpha transparency support (optional, default false)
> `options.quality` number  use the lowest number of colours needed to achieve given quality, sets palette to true (optional, default 100)

For whatever reason, pallete size for any quality of 15~100 seems to be the same (probably because that's max pallete size)

Try to test the same thing for another image type (say, jpg) and another image with lesser amount of colors

Comment: Tried it with a black and white image and saw an actual change with the image size though I couldnt really tell a difference with the image due to the nature of the image. I did notice anything above 75% quality will result in an image that takes more space which doesnt really make sense... the original image's size was 1,684KB, 75 was 1,658kb and 80 was 1,739kb. What would the reason for that be?

(sorry for the late reply, had a lot of other things to do)